# I Can't Get The Value By Key in Object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm creating an image upload component which allows drag&drop or picking files in Vuejs. My problem is that when I insert some images, I can neither get the image data by using keys nor loop in the result object.

### Edit (no need to read the original post down below)

After the reply of str, I changed my function to promise and some other interesting thinks have happened. My new function is:

```
OnDrop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    let fileArray = Array.from(e.dataTransfer.files);
    let addImages = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      for (let file of fileArray) {
        this.addImage(file);
        if (this.$props.multipleFiles === "false") break;
      }
      resolve();
    });
    addImages.then(() => {
      this.emittingData();
    });
  }
},
addImage(file) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = e => {
        let fileItem = {
            base64: e.target.result,
            name: file.name,
            type: file.type
        };
        this.files.push(fileItem);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
},
emittingData() {
    let emitData = {
        images: this.files,
        fileFor: this.$props.whichImage,
        type: this.sourceType
    };
    myUploader.$emit("insertImage", emitData);
}
```

In the parent component, I'm getting the emitted data like so:

```
myUploader.$on("insertImage", insert => {
    this.images = insert.images
    console.log(this.images);
    // returns:
    // [__obj__: Observer
    //     0: {__obj__: Observer
    //          base64: (...)
    //          name: (...)
    //          type: (...)
    //     }
    //     1: {__obj__: Observer
    //          base64: (...)
    //          name: (...)
    //          type: (...)
    //     }
    //     __ob__: Observer
    //     And some other things
    //        }
    // ]
    console.log(this.images[0]);
    // keeps returning undefined
    // 
});
```

When I execute the codes up above "images" object in VueDevTools becomes:

```
images: Array[2]
    0: Object
        base64: "data:image/png;base64,...
        name: filename.png
        type: image/png
    1: Object
        base64: "data:image/png;base64,...
        name: othername.png
        type: image/png
```

I think even more interestingly, when I add an img element into DOM like so

```
<img :src="images[0].base64">
```

it displays the image while Console throws

```
Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'base64' of undefined".
```

When I remove img tag, that error disappears.

Long story short:

1. I have an object that console says its 0 index is undefined despite the fact that it's clearly there.
2. I have an image displayed on screen that console says not exist.

When I change myUploader.$on function to setTimeout, it works, but I don't want to do that. Modified and working version of that function is:

```
myUploader.$on("insertImage", insert => {
  if (insert.fileFor === "featured") {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.images = insert.images[0].base64;
    }, 50);
  }
});
```

Can someone please help me on this one?

### Original Post

Here is my Drop function in child component:

```
OnDrop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    let fileArray = Array.from(e.dataTransfer.files);
    for (let file of fileArray) {
      this.addImage(file);
      if (this.$props.multipleFiles === "false") return;
    }
    console.log(typeof this.files);
    // returns: object.
    // I don't know why because it's defined as an empty array in data object,
    // in addImage() function down below, I push the values in it as it's an array,
    // VueDevtool tells it's an array. But typeof returns object. 
    console.log(this.files);
    // returns:
    // [__obj__: Observer
    //     0: {__obj__: Observer
    //          base64: (...)
    //          name: (...)
    //          type: (...)
    //     }
    //     1: {__obj__: Observer
    //          base64: (...)
    //          name: (...)
    //          type: (...)
    //     }
    //     __ob__: Observer
    //     And some other things
    //        }
    // ]
    // BTW, when I click on (...), I see the correct values are there.
    console.log(this.files[0]);
    // returns: undefined
    console.log(Object.values(this.files));
    // returns: []
    console.log(Object.keys(this.files));
    // returns: []
    this.files.forEach(image =>
      console.log("image :", image)
      // returns: literally nothing, not even null or undefined.
      // I tried too many other loops and the results were the same.
    );
},

addImage(file) {
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = e => {
    let fileItem = {
      base64: e.target.result,
      name: file.name,
      type: file.type
    };
    this.files.push(fileItem);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

When I look at the "files" object in VueDevtools, I see that it's an ordinary element like the others.

```
files: Array[2]
    0: Object
        base64: "data:image/png;base64,...
        name: filename.png
        type: image/png
    1: Object
        base64: "data:image/png;base64,...
        name: othername.png
        type: image/png
```

My question is, how can I get the the base64 value?
this.files[0].base64 thrown "base64 of undefined" error.

Interestingly, at least for me, I have an image element with v-for and it displays the image by using base64 string.

```
<img v-for="image in files" :src="image.base64">
```

Comment: array[0].base64?

Comment: this.files[0].base64 thrown "base64 of undefined" error.

Comment: The array is filled asynchronously and when you execute `OnDrop` it is still an empty array. The browser console logs objects at the moment of their expansion, not at the moment of when they were logged.

Comment: `:src="..."` or `v-bind:src=""` instead of `src="..."`

Comment: @str You are right. I tried it with settimeout and it worked. Now I need to create a promise. Thanks.

Comment: @Emils It's just a typo. In the real code it's :src="..." but thanks.